# Работа с классами наследниками Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Имеется иерархия классов вопросов, доступных при создании теста (иерархия упрощена для примера):

```
public class BaseQuestion
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Pictire Pictire { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOneAnswer : BaseQuestion
{
    public int RightAnswerId { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionManyAnswer : BaseQuestion
{
    public List<int> RightAnswerId { get; set; }
}
```

В контексте данных добавляю

```
DbSet<BaseQuestion> BaseQuestion{ get; set; }
```

Лучшим вариантом наследования думаю здесь будет `Table per Concrete class` [TPC] (поправьте, если не так). Объект теста имеет коллекцию типа `BaseQuestion`. Каждый тип вопроса должен иметь своё представление на клиенте. Вопросы планируется передавать в `Json` с использованием `WebAPI` и уже на клиенте в `KnockoutJS` строить разметку. Типов вопросов будет 7 +/-2.

Теперь вопросы:

1. Какие существуют удобные способы определить конкретный тип вопроса в коллекции базового типа. Первое, что приходит в голову, это пытаться выполнить приведение ко всем производным типам, но уверен, что есть варианты получше.
2. Как в `Json` помечать тип вопроса, чтобы клиент мог корректно его отобразить. Достаточно ли завести строковое поле с типом вопроса или для этого существуют другие механизмы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для "определения типа" сушествует ООП, а именно виртуальные методы. Вместо того, чтобы писать а-ля switch по всем типам, следует определить метод в базовом классе, который будет выполнять необходимую операцию, и который вы можете переопределить в потомках.

   Есть мапперы типов, если вы не собираетесь использовать сущности во всех слоях. Но в конечном счёте всё равно следует использовать виртуальные методы.
2. Зависит от того, как вы собираетесь потреблять ваш JSON. В принципе достаточно сериализовать свойство, которое возвращает `this.GetType().Name`. Этот же способ используется в EF для дискриминаторов в TPH (table per hierarchy).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Я собирался использовать виртуальные методы, например для создания логики подсчёта баллов за вопрос, но теперь постараюсь всё организовать с их использованием.

Answer (score 2):

Хоть про это вы и не спрашивали, я бы воздержался от использования TPC. С этим подходом связано множество неочевидных моментов - к примеру, конфликт первичных ключей в кеше EF - ведь с точки зрения БД это разные таблицы, и первичные ключи в них могут быть одинаковыми. TPH или TPT выглядят лучше.

Кроме того, лучше вообще воздержаться от построения иерархий там, где этого не требуется. Так, в вашем случае вы же все равно должны хранить для каждого вопроса список ответов - почему бы не хранить для каждого ответа булев флаг, означающий, является он правильным или нет?

В таком случае свойство RightAnswerId  вообще уходит из сущности, делая единственным различием QuestionOneAnswer и QuestionManyAnswer форму представления вопроса пользователю (чекбоксы или радиобаттоны). Но тогда иерархия становится ненужной, оказывается достаточно свойства-перечисления с указанием типа вопроса.

Отказ от иерархии решает одновременно обе проблемы. Ну а если иерархия все же нужна - см. ответ Athari.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что не дали мне совершить ошибку, я в вопросе как раз указал, что не уверен в этом моменте. А иерархия мне всё-равно понадобится, потому что есть например вопросы в которых требуется указать сопоставления или выбрать область на изображении.